# loading list page wise in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a XML file and in that there is some images and text to load in the list view. I have a custom adapter to upload the data in a list view. i have common cell for each list item. 
I want that when list is loading it only fetches for 10 data items and load them to list and when user scroll the list then it fetches next 10 items...

I have seen some of the example in some places but didn't get what i want.
can any body please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)... it does the trick perfectly